# Get a other node in JavaFX after mousePressed

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a List buttons. I need to be able to click one then do an action one it, but also click one, keep click then drag mouse to an other one then release click on the second one and both need to do an action.

in the Javadoc, it is said that :

> all subsequent mouse events are delivered to the same node until the button is released. 
>   https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseEvent.html

It is mentioned that i need to activate press-drag-release.

I have read that I need to calling startFullDrag() inside of a DRAG_DETECTED event handler.

> Full press-drag-release gesture can be started by calling startFullDrag() (on a node or scene) inside of a DRAG_DETECTED event handler. https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/MouseDragEvent.html

Here is my code :

```
// I create a list of buttons
// I add the EventHandler
private void setButtonNumbers(String number) {
    for (char ch : number.toCharArray()) {
        Button btn = new Button(ch + "");
        btn.getStyleClass().add("btnNumber");
        btn.setOnMouseClicked(clickOnNumber(btn));
        this.numbers.add(btn);
    }
}

private EventHandler<MouseEvent> clickOnNumber(Button btn) {
    EventHandler<MouseEvent> event;
    event = (MouseEvent t) -> {
        btn.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #" + getAColor());
    };
    return event;
}
```

Do I need th startFullDrag() when btn.setOnDragEntered(), then when btn.setOnMousePressed() do setMouseTransparent(true) then set it to false when Released as mentioned :

> You can achieve this by calling setMouseTransparent(true) on the dragged node in a MOUSE_PRESSED handler and returning it back to false in a MOUSE_RELEASED handler.

I've tried this, but I can figure on how the get something like this :

```
btn.setOnMouseClicked(// do something);
// Get the button where the mouse has been released and do something with that button.
```

Is it any exemple about what I am trying to achive?

Comment: Please show a SSCCE that demonstrates what you want to try and how you are stuck.

Comment: I want to do like the last lines. If I click on btn1, I keep the click then I release the click on btn2, I want both the button to do an action, btn1 will be triggered onMouseClicked. How do I get btn2 to "catch" the event and do something? I tried btn2.onMouseReleased() but it only affect btn1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer with this one :
[Can't get mouse event from any other javafx 8 node after getting MOUSE_PRESSED event from one node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26420701/cant-get-mouse-event-from-any-other-javafx-8-node-after-getting-mouse-pressed-e)

All I needed to do is :

```
        btn.setOnDragDetected(mouseEvent -> btn.startFullDrag());
        btn.setOnMouseReleased(// do something);
        btn.setOnMouseDragReleased(// do something with event triggered from an other node);
```