# JavaFX trigger Mouse Release event without having first triggered a Mouse Press event

Tags: java, events, javafx

I have a radio button which I want the user to be able to release a mouse click on after pressing the mouse from another component. In effect; the user would press on a different component, drag their mouse to this radio button, and release their mouse, triggering a a mouse release event.

However, this the method I am using doesn't allow me to do this.

```
radioButton.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, event -> System.out.println("RELEASE!"));
```

I only get the `"RELEASE!"` message in the console when releasing the mouse after pressing on the radio button. How can I make it so I can trigger the release event only?

Thanks.

Comment: I think that won't work als your event "Starts" in another component. The only solution i can think of would be listening for drag entered event

Comment: You're absolutely right. The working solution detects for a `MouseDragEvent.MOUSE_DRAG_RELEASED` event which will only trigger when you have used `startFullDrag()` on a `DRAG_DETECTED` event.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26420701/cant-get-mouse-event-from-any-other-javafx-8-node-after-getting-mouse-pressed-e/26424180#26424180

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `MouseDragEvent.MOUSE_DRAG_RELEASED` event in place of the `MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED` event and use `startFullDrag()` on a `DRAG_DETECTED` event (otherwise it won't detect the drag).

In effect:

```
radioButton.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, event -> System.out.println("RELEASE!"));
//The starting node in which the drag is started
node.setOnDragDetected(event -> node.startFullDrag());
```