# don't recieve mouse press event on child node JavaFX

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I want draw path between two imageview same as picture

[[image: picture].](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFVSo.png)

this path start from one of these imageview by mouse press, continue by mouse press and move event on pane and must be end in another imageview by mouse press.here is the problem after first mouse press didn't recieve any mouse press event on imageviews, the event just recieves on the pane becuase of that draw line didn't stop. what is wrong in my code ?

here's my controller code :

```
public class DrawLine {
    @FXML
    ImageView imageView1 ;
    @FXML
    ImageView imageView2 ;
    @FXML
    AnchorPane pane ;
    private  Line currentLine ;
    private  String state ;
    private DoubleProperty mouseX = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    private DoubleProperty mouseY = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

    @FXML
    private  void initialize(){
        state = "dfkl" ;
        imageView1.setPreserveRatio( false);
        imageView2.setPreserveRatio( false);
        imageView1.setOnMousePressed( event -> {
            imageMousePress( event);
        });
        imageView2.setOnMousePressed( event -> {
            imageMousePress( event);
        });
        pane.setOnMousePressed( event ->  {
            paneMousePress( event) ;
        });
        imageView2.setPickOnBounds(false);
        imageView1.setPickOnBounds(false);
        pane.setOnMouseMoved( event -> {
            paneMouseMove( event);
        });

    }


    public  void paneMouseMove( MouseEvent e) {
        if( this.state.equals("DRAWLINE") && this.currentLine != null) {
            makeLine( e);
        }
    }
    public void paneMousePress( MouseEvent e) {
        if( this.state.equals("DRAWLINE") && this.currentLine != null) {
            endLine(e);
            startLine(e);
        }
    }
    private  void  startLine( MouseEvent e ){
        currentLine = new Line();
        currentLine.setStyle( "-fx-stroke: #a86a6a ; -fx-stroke-width: 5");
        currentLine.setStartX( e.getSceneX());
        currentLine.setStartY(e.getSceneY());
        mouseX.set( e.getSceneX()) ;
        mouseY.set( e.getSceneY());
        currentLine.endXProperty().bind(mouseX);
        currentLine.endYProperty().bind(mouseY);
        pane.getChildren().add(currentLine);
    }
    private  void  endLine (  MouseEvent e){
        currentLine.endXProperty().unbind();
        currentLine.endYProperty().unbind();
        currentLine.setEndX(e.getX());
        currentLine.setEndY(e.getY());
        currentLine = null;
    }
    private  void makeLine( MouseEvent e){
        mouseX.set(e.getX());
        mouseY.set(e.getY());
    }

    private void imageMousePress( MouseEvent event){
        if( currentLine == null){
            startLine(event);
            state = "DRAWLINE" ;
        }else if( currentLine != null & state.equals("DRAWLINE")){
            endLine( event);
        }
    }
}
```

help me please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get mouse event from any other javafx 8 node after getting MOUSE\_PRESSED event from one node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26420701/cant-get-mouse-event-from-any-other-javafx-8-node-after-getting-mouse-pressed-e)

Comment: this two post have diffrent event handling , they are not same :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dragging the end point of the line around, the end is positioned below the mouse cursor. This way the target of the mouse event is the `Line`, not the `ImageView` and since there is no event handler for the event for the `Line` that consumes it, the event is delivered to the parent of the `Line` which is the `AnchorPane`, not the `ImageView`.

To fix this set the `mouseTransparent` property of the `Line` to `true`:

```
private void startLine(MouseEvent e) {
    currentLine = new Line();
    currentLine.setMouseTransparent(true);
    ...
}
```

Also you should consume the events for the `ImageView`s to not trigger the event handler for the `AnchorPane` too:

```
imageView1.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
    imageMousePress(event);
    event.consume();
});
imageView2.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
    imageMousePress(event);
    event.consume();
});
```

Also note that `x` and `y` properties of the `MouseEvent` are relative to the coordinate system of the `Node` where the handler is added.

```
private void endLine(MouseEvent e) {
    currentLine.endXProperty().unbind();
    currentLine.endYProperty().unbind();
    currentLine.setEndX(e.getX());
    currentLine.setEndY(e.getY());
    currentLine = null;
}
```

needs to be changed to

```
private void endLine(MouseEvent e) {
    currentLine.endXProperty().unbind();
    currentLine.endYProperty().unbind();
    currentLine = null;
}
```

Furthermore if there are a limited number of states, I recommend using a `enum` instead since this way you get compile time checks for typos. Using strings for this purpose you could accidentally add bugs, e.g. if you accidentally use `"DRAWLlNE"` instead of `"DRAWLINE"` which can be hard to spot. Additionally enum constants can be compared using `==`.

```
private enum States {
    DRAWLINE
}
```

Comment: thank you sooo mutch,it's work. I'm new to this field.Can you suggest me some links to get stronger in the context of event handling? please

Comment: @MahbubehSheidaie https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/processing.htm#CEGJAAFD could help. As for specific event types the javadoc of the `on<Event>` property and the javadoc of the event type are usually helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and attention